# Vim: Edit file starting from ancestor project directory

Tags: vim, filepath

I have a multiple working directories of a git repository on my machine, and when I have files from each open in vim I would like to be able to open a new file starting at the top level project directory that contains the current buffer file.

So for example, let's say I have these files open in buffers:

```
~/testing/MyProject/src/main.cc
~/mirror/MyProject/src/lib/module.h
```

If I am editing the `module.h` buffer, I want to be able to type `:e <something?>` and have it autocomplete to `~/mirror/MyProject/`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once common method is to keep your current working directory set to the root of your project.

However if you do change your current working directory then you may want to look at something like [fugitive.vim](https://github.com/tpope/vim-fugitive)'s `:Gedit` command which can be used to edit files relative the the repository's root. e.g. `:Gedit /foo.txt`

Comment: wow, fugutive.vim is pretty awesome! Thanks for the pointer!!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work by adding a `cabbr <expr> /` to my `.vimrc`:

```
" Makes // expand to the containing MyProject directory.
cabbr <expr> / FindMyProjectInPath()

function FindMyProjectInPath()
  let path=expand("%:p:h")
  while path != "/" && fnamemodify(path,":t") != "MyProject"
    let path = fnamemodify(path, ":p:h:h")
  endwhile

  return path
endfunction
```

So then if I'm editing `~/mirror/MyProject/src/lib/module.h`, I can type `:e //` and it expands to `:e ~/mirror/MyProject/`.

If I'm not in a MyProject directory, it will remain a `//`: if I'm editing `~/other_project/main.cpp`, then `:e //` won't expand.

The first `/` you type matches the `cabbr <expr> /` and the second one makes it expand.

You could maybe also use a variable to allow "MyProject" to be set dynamically while editing.

Comment: Be careful with that abbreviation as it will also expand during searches as well. I would suggest you take a look at `:h getcmdtype()` so you can guard against those cases